# Because every version of flutter_goldens from sdk depends on pedantic 1.7.0 and flutter_gallery depends on pedantic 1.8.0+1

Tags: flutter

I download flutter gallery app from github , when tried to build it and get the dependencies with flutter get dependencies it show me the below error

```
Because every version of flutter_goldens from sdk depends on pedantic 1.7.0 and flutter_gallery depends on pedantic 1.8.0+1, flutter_goldens from sdk is forbidden.
So, because flutter_gallery depends on flutter_goldens any from sdk, version solving failed.
```

Comment: Have you checked [this article](https://pratikbutani.medium.com/flutter-2-upgrade-flutter-version-solving-failed-error-33ac1087cb6b)

Answer (score 3):

I solved the problem by switching from beta to master channel :
to see the actual channel run

```
flutter channel
```

and to switch to master cannel run :

```
flutter channel master
```